# SlidingPaneLayout click on overlay

Tags: android

I created a SlidingPaneLayout with disabled swipe option

```
public class SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe extends SlidingPaneLayout {
    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The layout: where `includeSide` is the side menu and `includeMain` is the main layout

```
<com.mypackage.SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe
        android:id="@+id/slidingPaneMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/includeSide"
            layout="@layout/layout_side"/>

         <include
            android:id="@+id/includeMain"
            layout="@layout/layout_main"/>

</com.mypackage.SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe>
```

The menu is opened by button and on the remaining `includeMain` there is an overlay.
I want to close the menu by clicking the overlay area.
I trying to add `onClickListener` to root layout of the `includeMain`:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/header_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

The code:

```
mLayoutMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mSlidingPane.isOpen()){
                    mSlidingPane.closePane();
                }
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer is more simple than I thought:

```
public class SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe extends SlidingPaneLayout {
    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlidingPaneLayoutNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(isOpen()){
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now it can be closed by click & swipe.